# 2 Extends en blade

Tags: laravel, blade

es una duda bastante novata.  pero  me gustaría saber si puedo utilizar 2 @extends dentro de una sola plantilla blade, (que uno quede dentro del otro).

intente hacer lo siguiente, pero se separan :

```
@extends('parcial.layout')//plantilla maestra
@section('contenido') //seccion de la plantilla maestra para el contenido
    @extends('parcial._tabla')// plantilla de tabla extendida dentro de la de plantilla maestra
        @section('thead')
            <tr>
                <th>Hola</th>
                <th>Hola</th>
                <th>Hola</th>
                <th>Hola</th>
            </tr>
        @endsection
        @section('tbody')
             <tr>
                <td>Hola</td>
                <td>Hola</td>
                <td>Hola</td>
                <td>Hola</td>
            </tr> 
        @endsection
        @section('paginate','f')
@endsection
```

mi propósito es poder utilizar los estilos, el script y la estructura de la tabla en las vistas que la necesite , pero con sus respectivos datos.

Gracias

Comment: Si utilizas laravel > 7.x, puedes utilizar [componentes](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#components)

Answer (score 0):

no se si se pueda.  pero se puede hacer un extend a la plantilla master , para hacer extend desde vista, de la siguiente manera :

// plantilla para tabla

```
@extends('parcial.layout')
@section('contenido')
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between col-10 py-1">
        <div>
            @section('nuevo',route('mejora.equipos.create'))
        </div>
        <form class="d-flex justify-content-end">
            <input  class="rounded-left" type="search" name="f">
            <button  class="rounded-right">Buscar</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="table-responsive col-11">
        <table class="filter table table-sm" style="white-space: nowrap">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                @yield('thead')
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @yield('tbody')
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            @yield('paginate',' ')
        </div>
    </div>
    @endsection
```

// plantilla para vista

```
@extends('parcial._tabla')
@section('nuevo',route('mejora.equipos.create'))
@section('thead')
    <tr>
        <th>Equipo</th>
        <th>Serial/Codigo</th>
        <th>Estado</th>
        <th>Ubicacion</th>
    </tr>
@endsection
@section('tbody')
    @foreach($equipos as $equipo)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$equipo->equipo}}</td>
        <td>{{$equipo->serial}}</td>
        <td>{{$equipo->estado}}</td>
        <td>{{$equipo->ubicacion}}</td>

    </tr>
    @endforeach
@endsection
@section('paginate',$equipos->appends(['f'=> request('f')])->render())
```

(no se si sea la mejor manera pero es la que me funciono) la dejon aca por si a alguien mas le llegara a servir